# static variables in multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

`I found that declaring a variable as static makes no sense` in **Multi-Threading**. I assume that, this is because of `every thread has its own stack`. Is this the only reason?

I know that `static variables should be used within synchronized block`. but why?

Comment: How do you mean 'makes no sense'?

Comment: i meant that the value is not common on each thread

Comment: _I found that declaring a variable as static makes no sense in Multi-Threading_ `[citation needed]`

Comment: Check this out:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/8432327/2517719

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> static makes no sense in Multi-Threading.

**Im afraid you are making the reverse statement**. Static variable is a shared resource, which can be used to exchange some information among different threads. And we need to be careful while accessing such a shared resource. Hence, we need to make sure that the access to static variables in multi-threaded environment is synchronized.

> every thread has its own stack

This is a correct statement. `Each thread has its own stack but they share the process heap.` Stack holds only the local variables and not the variables on the heap. Static variables are stored in the `PermGen` section of the heap and hence the access to them should be well guarded.

Comment: So would `static int a` go into heap or stack memory then?

Comment: @Juned Ahsan , can you please let me know how can i verify  - "threads share the process heap."

Comment: @shivam static variables are stored in heap, so you can check that using different threads.

Answer (score 6):

Because first part of question is already answered, I will try to answer on second question.

> I know that static variables should be used within synchronized block. but why?

Because if you don't use [atomic](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html), operations with variables are not atomic. That's why you should block variables while working with them. But in real world, you can use **volatile** keyword, that will guarantee you, that threads will have actual values of variable.

Answer (score 3):

If you change a variable in a multithreaded environment, the new value may not neccessarily visibile as it might be cached. This is also true for static variables of course. If you don't use a synchronized block you might consider using `volatile` instead. This will also guaruantee that the various threads get an updated copy, without the need of synchronizing.
Wether `volatile` is enough four your application depends on your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

Add `volatile` to your static declaration.

`volatile` will guarantee any other thread will see the most recent value of the variable. So, with volatile it will make sense.

However, `volatile` will not guarantee atomicity. If you write to your variable from more than one thread you might want to use atomics or `synchronize` block.

I think `volatile` will be fine.