# Is a ReentrantLock safe enough to protect multithreaded access to a static variable

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized, static-members, reentrantlock

I have a class with static variables, and multiple threads will have instances of this class.

The static variable I'm concerned with is a `Thread`, that will pop a message from a queue and send it in an email, until the queue is empty. Every time a message is added to the queue, I check to see if the Thread is alive. If not, I restart it.

```
if (mailThread == null)
{
    mailThread = new Thread(mailSender);
    mailThread.start();
}
else if (!mailThread.isAlive())
{
    mailThread = new Thread(mailSender);
    mailThread.start();
}
```

In [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17500259/static-variables-in-multithreading), it was said that static variables should be used within a synchronized block.

My question is, would it be safe to just use a `ReentrantLock` for these if checks? Or do I need to use `synchronized`? Or both?

Comment: _...I check to see if the Thread is alive. If not, I restart it._  +1 for thinking about availability, but if you want a thread to always be available, a better strategy is to write a thread that never dies.  (I'm assuming that this `mailThread` does not execute any foreign code.  If you _do_ need to execute foreign code, you're probably better off sandboxing it in its own, separate process.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either ReentrantLock or a synchronized block. Both are equally safe. Although there is a difference in performance in certain situations. Check out these benchmarks: [Benchmark 1](http://vanillajava.blogspot.de/2011/07/synchronized-vs-lock-performance.html) [Benchmark 2](http://blog.takipi.com/java-8-stampedlocks-vs-readwritelocks-and-synchronized/).

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html):

> A reentrant mutual exclusion Lock with the same basic behavior and
>   semantics as the implicit monitor lock accessed using synchronized
>   methods and statements, but with extended capabilities. A
>   ReentrantLock is owned by the thread last successfully locking, but
>   not yet unlocking it. A thread invoking lock will return, successfully
>   acquiring the lock, when the lock is not owned by another thread. The
>   method will return immediately if the current thread already owns the
>   lock. This can be checked using methods isHeldByCurrentThread(), and
>   getHoldCount().

So a `ReentrantLock` must be safe enough.