# Java TimerTask not updating static field

Tags: java, timer, static, synchronization, timertask

Hello I have this custom TimerTask :

```
public class TimerTaskPerso extends TimerTask {
private static boolean i =  false;
@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println(i);
    if(i){
        System.out.println("m here");
        return;
    }
    i= true;
    System.out.println("ok");

    try {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {

    }
    System.out.println("bye");
    i= false;
}
}
```

And I am calling it like that :

```
new Timer().schedule(new TimerTaskPerso(), 1,500);
```

But the task keeps showing :

```
false
ok
bye
false
ok
false
```

I am supposed to see "m here" message, I tried this without creating Custom TimerTask and by using AtomicBoolean but same result.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you are thinking it will print `"m here"` as output. You are setting `i=false` again. So it will not print that message. In order to print that message you should comment this line `i= false;`. After commenting this line the output in my IDE is:

```
false
ok
bye
true
m here
true
m here
```

Please go through these for more information on static variables: [static variables in multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17500259/static-variables-in-multithreading) and this also [Are static variables shared between threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4934913/are-static-variables-shared-between-threads)

Comment: Please see my comment to @user7 response

Comment: You want that some other thread should see the updated i value as true, but it will  not because static variable makes local cache and it won't reflect in other thread.

Comment: I don't know a cache mechanism behind static variables, can you explain more please

Comment: Please go through this: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17500259/static-variables-in-multithreading> and this also <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4934913/are-static-variables-shared-between-threads>

Comment: The link gave me interesting information about what I wanted to know, In fact variables values are not updated instantly unless they are synchronized, or they are volatile, please respond to the question with the link so I accept it

Comment: Updated the answer with the links !!

Answer (score 0):

When the `TimerTask`'s run method starts, `i` will be *false*. Then it is set to *true*. But after sleeping for 3 seconds, `i` is again set to *false*.

During the next run, `i` will start off as *false*. And this goes on..

You have to remove you last assignment to `i` to make it become *true* after the first run. With this, it will print `m here` on subsequent runs.

Comment: But when sleeping for 3000 millis, there will be other tasks executed at a rate of 1 every 500 millis, based on this, some run() calls should occurs while i is true, check the timer schedule I've included in the question