# Java ScheduledExecutorService cancel doesn't work

Tags: java, timer

I use `ScheduledExecutorService` to start a timer that runs periodically, but this timer can't be canceled after I calling the `cancel()`:

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class Monitor {
    private static ScheduledFuture<?> timerCtrl;
    private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduExec = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1, StatmonitorThreadFactory.getInstance());

    private void startTimer() {
        timerCtrl = scheduExec.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MonitorTimer(), 5, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    public boolean cancelMonitorTimer() {
        if (timerCtrl != null) {
            timerCtrl.cancel(false); //both timerCtrl.isDone() and timerCtrl.isCancelled() return true
            LOG.error("{} {}", timerCtrl.isDone(), timerCtrl.isCancelled());
            if (!timerCtrl.isCancelled()) {
                LOG.error("timerCtrl cancel failed!");
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private class MonitorTimer implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            doPeriodicMonitor(); //call another function
        }
    }
}
```

At first, I call `startTimer()` to start my timer. After a while, I call `cancelMonitorTimer` to cancel and stop this timer and the function return true but timer still runs, `doPeriodicMonitor` is called every 5 seconds which is a period set by myself in `startTimer`.

Comment: This would be expected behavior if the monitoring task takes longer than 5 seconds and the thread pool is exhausted. You should add logging to record the latency of  `doPeriodicMonitor` and then ensure the scheduled rate is slower. You should also try it without the thread pool to rule out a bug  there.

Comment: @Gene In `doPeriodicMonitor()`, I start another two threads to do some work, si it illegal?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set true to `timeCrtl.cancel(true)` instead of `timerCtrl.cancel(false)` in your **cancelMonitorTimer()** method. This function further returns a boolean value **true** if the the task is cancelled successfully but if it returns **false** then it means it has already been completed.

Comment: not works, `mayInterruptIfRunning - true if the thread executing this task should be interrupted; otherwise, in-progress tasks are allowed to complete`, the parameter means to interrupt the running thread. In this case, my function `doPeriodicMonitor ` is called every 5 seconds

Answer (score 0):

I have found the reason that I should not use qualifier `static` in defining `timerCtrl`. But I still have no idea why can't. In my understanding, static value is per-class-loader but not [per-thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8432327/static-variables-and-multithreading-in-java), so that this variable will be shared between different threads.
In addition, class `Monitor` is a base class which was inherited by another class called `MonitorSon`, and the operation is called in the son class.

Comment: The `static` field is per-classloader.  As per the answer you quoted, there are synchronization problems when multiple threads are updating the same `static` field in terms of race conditions and memory sharing but they are still the same field.  If thread1 assigns `timeCtrl` then if it is static thread2 will overwrite thread1's value.